# Constraining parameters in NLS in R to be less than a value, or greater than a different value

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

The `nls` function in R comes with `upper` and `lower` arguments to specify the upper or lower limit of a parameter:

```
nls(Y~A*X,upper=list(A=40),algorithm="port")
```

However, how can I set a parameter constraint, for instance, on parameter A such that it must be less than 5, or greater than 10?

Comment: How many parameters have such a constraint?

Comment: Just one of the parameters. There are three parameters in my full model: Y=ax/(b+x) + c

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply solve it (by a call to nls) twice, applying one constraint in in the first problem and the other constraint in the second, and identify which of the two has the smaller sum of squares of error, thus yielding a least squares solution to the larger problem?

The same strategy would work for a small set of "outside this range" type constraints, but beyond a handful the combinatorial explosion will hurt. If the unconstrained problem is unimodal and if the parameters not highly correlated, one approach might be to fit the problem unconstrained and then start imposing constraints on variables that don't obey the bounds (which may in turn push other variables out of bounds). If problems are not so well behaved, you'd have to look to combinatorial optimization methods.